# FTP Directory Permission Issue: does granting access to a directory also grant access to other parallel directory?

Tags: windows, ftp, permissions

I have a FTP directory permission issue. Under the root directory of my FT directory I have 2 sub directory:

1. DirectoryA
2. DirectoryB

I have granted one machine with the read/write permission to `DirectoryB`. Does this mean that it will also have the same access to `DirectoryA`? If yes, is there anyway to solve this problem? I don't want to setup one FTP account for one machine.

**Edit: I am running on Windows ( XP and above) machine. Does OS make a difference here?**

Comment: what ftp daemon ? what os ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have given permission to user for a particular folder, he will not be able to access other FTP directories. He will get alert message 505 "Access Denied".

But make sure you have applied permission to that user and have removed other users from access control list of the folder.

Comment: Thanks, is there a link to what you claim here?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions, whether FTP or file system, flow down from a root. They do not jump across to parallel directories. If Directory A and DirectoryB each stem from the same root and the permissions are applied at that root then both will have the same permissions. Permissions applied specifically to DirectoryA will not automatically be applied to DirectoryB.

Comment: But isn't that user needs to have root directory permission before he can access the sub-directory?

Comment: Yes, but only sufficient access to be able to traverse it to the lower level, at which point there can be different permissions. This part depends greatly on the OS and the FTP software. I know you said it's Win XP but you haven't stated what FTP server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give access to a user not a machine.

Comment: Mind to elaborate more?

Comment: Give UserA read read permission at the root, then goto directory B and remove inheritence at the root of directory B assign userA via a local group say DirectoryB WRX permission to Directory B. Then create another local group for directory A say DirectoryA With WRX. Put user be in this group. This shoud be enough for you to seperate the access. 

configure the permissions to Directory A